# How to download video from url save it in directory and play using MPMovie player in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried till downloading but downloaded video is showing not supported  plz help thanks for help.

Here is my code:

Downloading video from url code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
    NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://cdn-fms.rbs.com.br/vod/hls_sample1_manifest.m3u8";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( urlData )
    {

        NSLog(@"urldata %@   ",urlData);
        NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"thefifle2.mov"];

        //saving is done on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"File Saved !%@",filePath);
             _url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
            [self playv];

        });
    }

});
```

Play downloaded video using MPMoviepLayercontroller

```
    NSURL *vedioURL;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);

NSString *fullpath;

for (NSString *apath in filePathsArray )
{
     fullpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:apath];
    vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];

}

 NSData *urlData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:vedioURL];
 NSLog(@" url data1 %@  ",urlData1);
NSLog(@"vurl %@",vedioURL);
MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
[videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried with some mp4 Examples worked for me

```
//download the file in a seperate thread.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
    NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( urlData )
    {

        NSLog(@"urldata %@   ",urlData);
        NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"demo2.mp4"];

        //saving is done on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"File Saved !%@",filePath);
             _url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];


        });
    }

});
```

Comment: That was my point, the original url was not an asset file. An m3u8 file is essentially an xml file, so you were trying to play an something akin to an xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that your URL doesn't actually point to a "video" file?

.m3u8 Files are not actual Asset files, rather, they are more akin to a playlist. They are used in HTTP Live Streaming and provide a location for "Segments" based on available bandwidth